# Filter Items from JSON Objects in PHP

Tags: php, json, filter

I have this Function/Method for filtering out a Blacklist of words in an `ARRAY()` using `array_filter` but I need to do something similar to my Objects in this code below...

JSON Objects

```
// Get JSON Object
$obj = json_decode($out);

// Iterate JSON Object
foreach($obj as $index => $user) {
    echo $user->id;
    echo $user->screen_name;
    echo $user->language;
    echo $user->location;
    echo $user->time_zone;
    echo $last_status_date;
    echo $user->status->text;


    // Filter out Objects that match the Blacklist


    // insert remainning into database here

}
```

My current Blacklist Filter Function

```
public function blacklistFilter($raw_array){

    //$data1 = array('Phillyfreelance' , 'PhillyWebJobs', 'web2project', 'cleanname');
    $data1 = array_filter($data1, function($el) {
            $bad_words = array('job', 'freelance', 'project', 'gig', 'word', 'news', 'studio');
            $word_okay = true;

            foreach ( $bad_words as $bad_word ) {
                if ( stripos($el, $bad_word) !== FALSE ) {
                    $word_okay = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return $word_okay;
    });
}
```

---

So I am curious if there is a simialr function for filtering objects as `array_filter` does for ARRAYS?

Ultimately my goal is to be able to pass hundreds of JSON Objects through a function and be able to filter out ones that match a set of words in the username, filter out ones that match a language, and filter ones out that match a location or time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except you want a solution `specifically for object` if not you don't need it

you are calling

```
  $obj = json_decode($out);
```

That is why you are getting an object .. if you call

```
 $obj = json_decode($out,true);
```

When second argument is `TRUE`, `json_decode` returned `objects will be converted into associative arrays.`

The response would be a array  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for documentation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand everything correctly, I don't think you even need a new PHP function for objects, and your filter seems overly complex.

```
$obj = json_decode($out);
$bad_words = array('job', 'freelance', 'project', 'gig', 'word', 'news', 'studio');
foreach((array)$obj as $key => $val)
{
    $word_okay = !in_array($val, $bad_words);
    if($word_okay){
        echo "{$val} is good";
    }
    else{
        echo "{$val} is bad";
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you want to be able to treat an object as an array when needed, but still keep it as an object. Otherwise this will initialize your JSON object as an array:

```
$obj = json_decode($out, true);
```

Comment: in_array is no good because I match words, like freelancer would be matched with my freelance word

Comment: You could always turn strict filtering on: in_array($val, $bad_words, true)
Unless, of course, $val itself could potentially be a non-string. Then the types won't match up. Whatever works best for you.